# Back up and restore MySQL from one server to another

Tags: mysql

In MySQL data folder I copy and paste it into another MySQL data folder. My DB is innodb.

Currently I have an issue after restoring the data, MySQL.sock file refreshing each and every moment. So phpMyAdmin frequently logged out, we can don't do any function like query, search, export etc. What is the issue going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the mysql-version the same? Make sure you copy the complete mysql-datadir because you can't transfer individual mysql databases by copy the database-folder from one server to another (as with myisam). InnoDb keeps some of their data/metadata in files like: ibdata1.

Please let us see the logfiles (common path: /var/log/mysql.log or look up the logpath and loglevel in the file: my.cnf).

In most cases it is better to dump the database / all databases and restore it on the other Server. You can do it by:

```
mysqldump -u [USER] -p'[PASSWORD]' [DATABASE] > /root/mysqldump.sql
```

After that you can transfer the dump to your second Server (for example with rsync):

```
rsync -arvz /root/mysqldump.sql [USER]@[IP-ADRESS]:/root/
```

Finally you restore the dump on your new server with:

```
mysql -u [USER] -p'[PASSWORD]' < /root/mysqldump.sql
```

Comment: Hi @apensiv , i copy the database folder from one server another server. All done. In phpmyadmin database showing data also showing. But same time i cant do anything like query , search export import everything i do its automatically goes logout. same time ** mysql.sock** refreshing every moment. Why? What is the problem